# NSURLRequest: PUT request with JSON body

Tags: objective-c, nsurlrequest

I am trying below request in POSTMAN and through Xcode

Result: Getting 200 Response from POSTMAN request and 1012 from Xcode

POSTMAN:Request

REQUEST TYPE: PUT

URL: https://www.somesite.com/v1/favorites

Headers:

Content-Type: "application/json"
Authorization: AUTH_TOKEN

```
{
"requestParameters": {
    "_id": 3598,
    "favorites": [{
        "_id": 1456,
        "contactName": "aaa",
        "contactUserName": "bbb"
    }]
}
}
```

== Objective-C ==

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL_STRING];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *jsonPostBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"requestParameters\":{\"_id\":%@,\"favorites\": [{\"_id\": %@,\"contactName\": \"%@\",\"contactUserName\":\"%@\"}]}}",USERID_STRING,CONTACT_ID_STRING,CONTACT_NAME_STRING,CONTACT_USERNAME_STRING];

NSData *postData = [jsonPostBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:AUTH_TOKEN forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:handler];
```

I tried printing `jsonPostBody` string and verified that it's a valid `JSON`. Can anyone help by pointing out if there's anything obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

-1012 error code is NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication .  It sounds like the server requested authentication (via a 401 response), but you did not have a NSURLConnection delegate handler for the NSURLAuthenticationChallenge.  Perhaps the auth header isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself. Apparently the Content-Type was invalid and replacing it 
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; resolved the issue.